# Laravel radio button name not showing in input request when radio button nothing selected

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
{!!Form::text('first_name','')!!}
{!!Form::text('last_name','')!!}

{!!Form::radio('status','1')!!}
{!!Form::radio('status','2')!!}
```

Above radio button nothing selected, when submit the input to controller,

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $inputArray = $request->all();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_R($inputArray);
    exit;
}
```

Below are the response for the input array:

```
Array
(
    [_token] => 0yavNy0XLB7YM4xSnKFR7LZqfwTqkybBum3tnkJQ
    [first_name] => 
    [last_name] => 
)
```

Why the radio input name(status) does not shows in request. I want the below response.

```
Array
(
    [_token] => 0yavNy0XLB7YM4xSnKFR7LZqfwTqkybBum3tnkJQ
    [first_name] => 
    [last_name] => 
    [status] =>
)
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a hidden field for `status` like this.

```
{!!Form::text('first_name','')!!}
{!!Form::text('last_name','')!!}

{!!Form::hidden('status','0')!!}

{!!Form::radio('status','1')!!}
{!!Form::radio('status','2')!!}
```

If `status` is not selected, value will be `zero`

Comment: If it works, you should accept the answer so that other people can be benefited from it. Thank you.